# Why this JQuery Ajax won't be cached

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my script. I want the result to be cached but it keeps sending requested requests if my mouse enters it again.

```
$('.poplist li').mouseenter(function(){
    t=$(this).parent().attr("rel");
    i=$(this).attr("rel");
    $.ajax({
        url:"/j/place",
        data:{"t":t,"tid":i},
        cache:true,
        success:function(data){
            data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            s=$('.left[rel='+t+']');
            s.find('.intro').html(data["intro"]);
            s.find('.shop-avat img').attr("src","http://img.douban.com/u/plao/"+data['img']);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Seems to be correct so far. Do you really have a second request or is it just your callback function executing again?
Did you console.log your data attributes? If they differ, the request won't be cached of course.

Comment: Which request is not being cached? The request to `/j/place` or the request to `http://img.douban.com/u/plao/"+data['img']`?

Comment: Also, are you *sure* the response is not being cached? Firebug will show a request, even if it serviced by the local cache (as opposed to the remote server)

Comment: @Dancrumb of course the whole request.

Comment: @scr4ve I checked the console, the request status is a 200

Comment: Is `/j/place` outputting any caching instructions? Maybe they override the `cache` directive?

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for your remind. I checked the header, it's due to my NGINX server added a 'no-cache' header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.ajax's `cache` option does *nothing* when set to `true`, and caching is entirely left up to the browser. If it is set to `false`, however, a cache-busting timestamp is appended to the request. That's all.

Update:
To see that this is so, take a look at the the source of jQuery.ajax, version 1.6.4, line 676, here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.4/src/ajax.js#L676

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is,

You may save the result `(data)` in a variable and you may use an `if` function before your ajax request. On mouse enter, if variable have no data stored, trigger ajax request, else, return false.